Modifying a variable in a single `Task.Run` versus using two
I encountered a question in using multiple tasks to modify a value.
Can any help explain what is going on here?
Please review the following code:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool test = true;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Before Sleep ! test:{test}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        test = false;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"After Sleep ! test:{test}");

    });
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (test)
        {
        }
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Console.WriteLine("Escape successfully ! "); // It works properly
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}

This code will print "Escape successfully ! "
But if I take out the second Task.Run, as follows, the "Escape successfully" will not print.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool test = true;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Before Sleep ! test:{test}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        test = false;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"After Sleep ! test:{test}");

    });
    while (test)
    {
    }
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    Console.WriteLine("Escape successfully ! "); // It will not work

    Console.ReadKey();
}

Update
When I trying the situation Ken White mentioned about, I found using mutiple not always working properly.
So maybe I sould simply always using volatile when I need modify a value with mutiple threads.
The following code is the code I tested.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool test = true;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Before Sleep ! test:{test}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        test = false;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"After Sleep ! test:{test}");

    });

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Into While");
        while (test)
        {
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Escape successfully ! "); // not print
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}


Can you be more specific about what exactly you don't understand?

Thank for response, I don't understand why the first one can working properly, and the second don't.
Both of them are difference thread.

Both version of your code behave the same for me.

They're also not necessarily threads. You've used tasks are not always run on different threads.

Can you please provide us the instructions required to see what you're seeing?

Hi Enigmativity, thank you for your trying, did you use the release for build configuration ?

In the first block, both Tasks are started at the same time and get the initial value of test while it's true, so both can execute. In the second block, the first Task gets the value as true, sets it to false, and the second portion of the code doesn't execute until after that happens. The while (test) is therefore false, and the loop doesn't execute.

@KenWhite - That shouldn't change the expected output.

@王楷瑞 - Did you state that in the question?

Hi @Enigmativity ,
Thanks for editing my grammatical errors and helping me clarify my question. I really appreciate it. I've updated my question.

Hi @KenWhite, sorry that I think your description has an error, if there have some new thread codes, the C# will excute the rest code first, and then run the code in new thread.Anyway, I tested your description, and updated that in question, thanks for your answering.

@王楷瑞 - Read Eric Lippert's blog on volatile: https://ericlippert.com/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/

Um, no. The code in both your posts launches the Task first, which means it is started first. It doesn't get skipped over so that the rest of the code gets run, and then things go back to the thread. But you can confirm this yourself - set a breakpoint on the first executable line in your code and run it under the debugger.


So maybe I sould simply always using volatile when I need modify a value with mutiple threads.

Certainly not "always", but yes: you do need to think about a few things, including enregistration which is I suspect what has happened here - but also synchronization more generally; and yes Volatile.Read and Volatile.Write would help with that - however, a hot loop on a bool is a terrible way to wait for something - literally anything else would be better - the obvious option in this case being to await or Wait() the first Task.

Hi Marc Gravell, Thanks for your sharing.
Yes I know about await, task ,etc. but my app need do things synchronously.
Anyway, thank you for sharing Volatile.Read and Volatile.Write, those are new to me !
have a good day sir.

@王楷瑞 task.Wait() is synchronous ("sync over async"), and would be much better than the hot loop
